# SQL Division shows as null in SSRS

Tags: sql, oracle, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to do some divisions in SQL and put them into an SSRS table object.

This SQL works, and the **result is 0.6**:

```
select testcol2/5 testcol from (select 3 testcol2 from dual)
```

[image]

But when i try to do the other way around (so divide with the column) the SSRS table **shows no value** instead of 1.6:

```
select  5/testcol2 testcol from (select 3 testcol2 from dual)
```

[image]

Please can someone help me how to get SSRS to show me the 1.6 value?

Comment: if you execute the dataset query from within SSRS, what is returned?

Comment: @AlanSchofield i have only text based designer available, i can check the outcome only if i use SSRS objects

Comment: Try casting the static values to compatible decimal or float data types.

    `select  CAST(5 as float) / testcol2 testcol from (select 3 testcol2 from dual)`

or just to test, simply add decimal places to the static value

    `select  5.00 / testcol2 testcol from (select 3 testcol2 from dual)`

Comment: @AlanSchofield thanks but this doesn't solve it, I am quite sure the code would produce outcome, SSRS is not displaying them

Comment: If there is no formatting on the textbox then the raw data will be shown. SSRS does not do anything different, it just gets the data from a dataset and displays it. Are you editing the RDL file by hand or is this RDLC ?

Comment: @AlanSchofield I do it by hand, so I create a new RDL file, set the connection, create a dataset, using the source and insert the SQL query as text, and add the fileds to the dataset. Then in the body i insert a table and add the column from the dataset. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @AttilaKozma Did my answer help you resolve this? If so, please mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty strange, but I was able to reproduce it. When I run the SQL in a different tool, I can confirm that the result is `1.666666...`, but SSRS isn't displaying it.

Here is a solution that works. Change the SQL to round the result:

```
select ROUND(5/testcol2, 2) as testcol2 
from (select 3 testcol2 from dual)
```

Now SSRS will display `1.67` as expected. And it will honor any additional number formatting that you place on the textbox as usual.

**Edit:**
To satisfy my curiosity, I dug in a little more. I used the `dump` function in Oracle to determine that it was using a length of 193. This works if you round with up to 28 decimal places. Anything more than that and SSRS won't display the value.

Comment: That is strange. I've been using SSRS for more years than I care to remember and I've not come across this. What happens if you simply format the textbox but leave the original recurring value in the dataset ? (sorry no time to test right now!)

Comment: @AlanSchofield Same here. Formatting the textbox didn't help I think it's a limit with the precision SSRS will accept. "No one would ever need more than 28 decimal places" right? lol